# Mensaje de éxito al enviar formulario

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

Hola estoy implementando un sistema de registro de mascotas y quiero que al momento de enviar el formulario envíen un mensaje de éxito, estoy utilizando sweetalert2, Quiere decir que al momento de dar click en enviar me envié el mensaje de éxito.
Les dejo una función que estaba realizando, gracias.

Función

```js
function enviarExitoCambio() {
  if (numRegisMascoCambio !== "" || docIdenDueMascoCambio !== "" || nombreNuevoDueCambio !== "" || apellidoNuevoDueCambio !== "" || correoNuevoDueCambio !== "" || tipoDocNuevoDueCambio !== "" || numeDocuNuevDueCambio !== "" || telFijoNuevDueCambio !== "" || celularNuevDueCambio !== "" || direccionNuevDueCambio !== "") {
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'top-end',
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Your work has been saved',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    })
  }
```

```html
 <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-perro btn-block"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#modalCambio"
                    onchange="enviarExitoCambio()" 
                  >
                    Enviar Solicitud
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
```